# GEdit not working for some users

Tags: gnome, 13.04, gedit, glib

I am using GEdit 3.8.2 on Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail with GNOME 3.8. I have two user accounts on my computer.

When I launch GEdit in my account, I get a window that is blank, and am not able to create or open any files. The terminal output shows:

```
(gedit:16768): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type `GtkSourceView'`

(gedit:16768): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `result != 0' failed

(gedit:16768): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_get_qdata: assertion `node != NULL' failed

(gedit:16768): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_get_qdata: assertion `node != NULL' failed

(gedit:16768): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_set_qdata: assertion `node != NULL' failed

(gedit:16768): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type `GtkSourceBuffer'

(gedit:16768): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `result != 0' failed

(gedit:16768): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_get_qdata: assertion `node != NULL' failed

(gedit:16768): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_get_qdata: assertion `node != NULL' failed

(gedit:16768): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_set_qdata: assertion `node != NULL' failed

(gedit:16768): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type `GtkSourceLanguage'

(gedit:16768): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `result != 0' failed
```

In any other account or as root, GEdit works normally. Please help!

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling it? `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gedit`

Comment: Yes, I've tried reinstalling...but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>I had this problem too and  the fix for me was to open *dconf-editor* and reset the *filebrowser* plugin settings:</strike>

[image: Screenshot of resetting gedit setting in dconf-editor]

<strike>I *believe* the problem for me was a root directory existing but not having sufficient permissions to read it. If that doesn't work you should probably go through all gedit settings for the user and reset to default.</strike>

**EDIT**

After this bug reappeared for me I did some grunt work and tracked this down to the "Code comment" plugin. To solve this open *dconf-editor* and navigate to *org=>gnome=>gedit=>plugins=>active-plugins* and either remove 'codecomment' or click "Set to Default".

[image]

The GNOME Bugzilla report is here: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=700867

Comment: Thank you so much! It's so good to have my favorite text editor back!